# How do I mitigate the forward slash problem for URLs of images after a WP migration?

Tags: images, urls, migration

I migrated my WP deployment from the old server to the new server. The site still has the same URL (i.e. http://my.site.com) but I've moved my WP deploy from the site URL to a subdirectory of said URL (i.e. the WP deploy used to be found at http://my.site.com, but now it's at http://my.site.com/blog).

The good news is that I've got all the textual content migrated. The bad news is that the images aren't loading correctly. I took a closer look at the URLs for images embedded in posts and they all look something like this:

```
<img style="padding: 7px;" src="/wp-content/uploads/image.jpg" alt="Image" width="172" height="154" align="right" border="0">
```

Note the forward slash in the `src` attribute. What's happening is that the browser is looking to load the image at http://my.site.com/wp-content/uploads/image.jpg. But the site is deployed at http://my.site.com/blog now. I can find the image if I cut and paste the URL into my browser and pre-prend the correct WP site URL (i.e.http://my.site.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/image.jpg).

What kind of WP kung-fu do I need to correct this?

I have read:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

I have looked at these:

http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/

And they don't exactly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit odd that there are root-relative URLs, WordPress by default uses absolute URLs when inserting images. However, probably the quickest fix is to open the SQL file in a text editor and just search and replace `src="/wp-content/` with `src="/blog/wp-content/`, or the absolute URL, whatever you prefer.

Comment: Can you point me to the documentation in the Codex on this? This is a good suggestion, though.

Comment: I used this suggestion. Just for anyone that's looking at this as a solution. Use sed (I tried to use a text editor but my file was too large): `sed -E 's/<img([^>]+src=\\\")(\/wp-content[^>]+>)/<img\1https:\/\/my.site.com\/blog\2/g' < blog.mysql > blog.mysql.new` This is with whatever sed comes with Mac OS X 10.7.5

Answer (score 0):

Forward slash is a good thing to make sure that you are accessing the resource  from a path relative to the root domain

Why not just create a rewrite rule in the .htaccess like the one below and then always access it "/assets/img/". Makes more portable always

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^assets/img/(.*) /wp-content/uploads/$1 [QSA,L]
```